# Where is the ‘default debugger’ setting located in VSCode's UI?

Tags: visual-studio-code, user-interface, default-settings, location

When you create a new project and run the ‘run without debugging’ command for the first time, VSCode suggests you choose a default debugger (see screen below). Where can I change that default debugger later in the user interface? [image: selection of default debugger]

P.S. I’m aware of the launch.json configuration file, but that’s not what I’m looking for. The editor stores that setting somewhere else even without that file. And I want to change that setting if I've chosen a wrong option for the first time.

Comment: The VSCode [Debugging chapter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) says that the file is `launch.json` located in a `.vscode` folder in your workspace, but other possibilities are in your [user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration) or [workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_workspace-launch-configurations).

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, launch.json is not what I’m looking for. As for the other options, there is no such setting in workspace settings (just checked, it's empty or user settings (because it’s a project level setting obviously).

Comment: If the documentation doesn't help, you could use a brute-force method to search all the files in the project folder for the name of the debugger. You could create a dummy project and specify a debugger that is easy to search (perhaps Chrome). An example product that I use for that is [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/?src=abt).

Comment: I've already tried that: did a search with `grep` in all the settings files `grep -inRwl -E 'deno' . --exclude-dir=*{Cached*,History,Cache,logs}*` and manually looked through the files but haven't managed to find a meaningful setting. And only after that went to Super User website

Comment: So you're on Linux. The field might be just a binary number which is the index into the list, so the text isn't there to be found. Well, the next check might be to set the debugger, then look for the file by it modification date, so it should be one of the latest to be updated. It might surprisingly not be in the project folder.

Comment: which one in the screenshot you are showing is the "default"? Are you referring to the two suggested items? (Deno and Node.js?, related source code: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.79.2/src/vs/workbench/contrib/debug/browser/debugAdapterManager.ts#L384). the suggested debuggers are the ones that are either activate early, or used before (in which case the solution could be to use the debugger type once). Does that answer your question?